# How to highlight multiple words in a PDF

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

How to highlight multiple words in a PDF?. i can able to use PDF open parameters. But unable to highlight multiple word at same time.

Please help me to sort it problem.

Regards
Dipen

Comment: Please show the code you are currently using to highlight a single word

Comment: Have you checked the first related question to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368425/highlight-search-terms-in-pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro. My requirement is exactly like Google Viewer. http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:2gqRQKstQzoJ:www.glencoe.com/sec/literature/litlibrary/pdf/hamlet.pdf+filetype:pdf+hamlet&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShjZQflLK8SeH43NGk4d83OC9Y2-LywV4DLLpg448dpATaev5_iuoK5aSawwImXagtRnms1a1KiYSx3MUY77ggwLbYAMCrpx50gfaz_dGfJP04tTdBD_sSVY1y_57fm3DSEPxC5&sig=AHIEtbQCxLuKM9Z8OWDMr8ekffLkbnVNAw .. if we search anything then it will highlight all the matched keyowrd .. can you please help me with some examples.. May be API...

Comment: Related: http://www.pdflib.com/tet-cookbook/tet-and-pdflib/highlight-search-terms/